# Как сравнить две схемы в базе данных Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Вопрос теоретический. Есть две схемы базе, в изначальном состоянии они были одинаковые по структуре, но в одной из схем сделал я много изменений, начиная с того,что в таблицах менялись первичные ключи, внешние ключи, добавлялись тригерры и секвенсы. Но, так как этого было много и я уже не помню последовательность действий. Можно ли сделать такой механизм скриптом, или может есть такой инструмент, чтобы сравнить схему с таблицами A и схему с таблицами B и если есть разница, то  структура например изменяется то есть изменения из A добавляются в B.

Comment: попробуйте вот это dbForge Schema Compare for Oracle

Comment: Спасибо за ответ попробую

Comment: Видимо только самому написать. Сравнить данные из служебных представлений (all_tab_coluns и им подобным) и перенести изменения из одной схемы в другую. А если лень, то Toad -> Database -> Compare либо механизм из pl/sql developer. По поводу скрипта - посмотрите https://habr.com/ru/post/148604/

Comment: Да я как раз лягушкой (TOAD) пользуюсь, а там подобный механизм есть сравнения и манипуляциями?